# How to use entire file as unique sample for classification in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, neural-network, classification, scikit-learn, data-mining

My dataset is split in different files, since i'm using EEG data collected for BCI (Brain-Computer Interface) classification. Here is what i have:

- Each `.txt` file that contains data of EEG signals of 16 electrodes for a period of 2 seconds at 256Hz. So it is a 512 x 16 (+1 column for class) matrix
- Each `.txt`file represents a single class. So each file is something like: `user_1_class_1.txt`, `user_1_class_2`, etc.
- I have 36 users and 5 classes, so there is 180 files in total

I am using `scikit-learn MLPClassifier` to classify this data but my first experiments gone totally wrong. After some research, i noticed that in BCI problems we must present the ***the entire file*** as a sample to the classifier.

That sounds a little confusing to me, tough i know that data is time-dependant. I'd be glad for an explanation on how to organize data and feed the `MLPClassifier`.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally read all files into pandas dataframes, do any cleaning or processing like that, then pass the underlying matrix out for actual training using the [**fit method**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.fit). I don't think it is as hard as you fear - have a look at [**this example here**](https://www.kaggle.com/ahmethamzaemra/mlpclassifier-example).

You need to have a single sample as a train matrix with shape `512 x 16` and a validation matrix that (I understand) would be a single value i.e. the class, which repeats the same value for all rows of EEG data. It matches the class name stored in the file name as well, right?

You will have 180 samples (one per file). You can split those into train and validation using [**`train_test_split`**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) from `sklearn`.

```
# imports
import os
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# List all files, stored e.g. in the folder called "data"
files = sorted([file for file in os.listdir("./data/") if f.endswith(".txt")])

# Read into pandas - might need to adapt based on structure of your txt files
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in files]
# Do any required cleaning on each dataframe - func takes and returns a df
clean_dfs = [func(df) for df in dfs]
```

Now get out the matrices using the dataframe `.values` attribute:

```
data = [df.values[:, 0:-1] for df in clean_dfs]  # take all but final column (the label)
labels = [df.values[0, -1] for df in clean_dfs]  # take first items in class column
```

Now you can create the train/val split:

```
X_tr, X_te, y_tr, y_te = create_train_test_split(data, values, test_size=0.2)
```

These can now be passed into the classifier's `fit` method~

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix
clf = MLPClassifier()            # define the classifier
clf.fit(X_tr, y_tr)              # train the classifier
predictions = clf.predict(X_te)  # make predictions on the test set
```

You can compute some metrics such as an [**accuracy score**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html):

```
score = accuracy_score(y_te, predictions)
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. However, it's not clear for me that your suggestion is treating each file as a single sample. Could you provide some explanation?

Comment: @joann2555 Each item in the list `data` is a matrix containing the data from a single file. This is then passed as a single sample (one of many, in the list `X_tr`) to the `fit` method.

Comment: n1k31t4 are you available for chatting, so i can show you what i have?